# Как отслеживать и выводить ошибки при разработке веб приложений Maven+Servlet+Tomcat используя IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat

Скажем я разрабатываю какое то веб приложение ну и в процессе не совсем правильно написал скажем контроллер и кидает меня сразу на error.jsp. Как мне отследить в какой строчке ошибка да и вообще полный стек ошибок вывести?

**Всё что угодно кроме логирования!**

Comment: Это называется логгирование, и вам придется научиться им пользоваться, если вы видите себя в роли Java программиста. Без вариантов.

Comment: Но оно не работает. Не вижу я своих логов в catalina. Запускаю всё из под IDEA

Comment: IDEA показывает консоль? Если ничего не предпринимать, то tomcat при запуске из под внешних программ пишет логи в консоль.

Comment: @Sergey не, консоль совсем не куда не годится. Должен быть способ добится работы логирования

Answer (score 2):

Вот такое логирование Netbeans автоматически вставляет в блоки `try catch`

```
try {
    ...
    throw new MyException();
    ...
} catch (MyException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Прекрасно пишется в лог Weldfly (а раньше и в лог Glassfish).
Всякое конечно может быть, но вряд ли на Tomcate будет работать иначе.
Может фильтр (или как он там точно называется) настроен игнорировать логи по разным параметрам: уровень ошибки - `Level.SEVERE` `WARNIG` `INFO` пр., подсистема - параметр `getLogger(String subsystem)`

Вот кстати в руководстве Tomcat говорится:

> This java.util.logging implementation is enabled by providing certain
>   system properties when starting Java. The Apache Tomcat startup
>   scripts do this for you, but if you are using different tools to run
>   Tomcat (such as jsvc, or running Tomcat from within an IDE), you
>   should take care of them by yourself.

Если запускать родными скриптами, то система логирования `java.util.logging` включается автоматически. А если запускать из IDE, то надо где-то что-то подкрутить

Comment: Родное логирование которое пишет tomcat работает (catalina показывает) но то что пытаюсь писать в лог я не пишется